# Configuring TortoiseHg for Bitbucket in Ubuntu

Tags: software-rec, tortoise-hg

I have installed TortoiseHg on Ubuntu and created an account at Bitbucket. I am configuring an SVN for the first time for my grad project. Can any one help as to how to configure TortoiseHg with bitbucket so that I can check in files.
Is there an alternate SVN provider-client combination I can setup easily.